# Debugging on Device - Visual Studio Xamarin

Tags: android, visual-studio, debugging, xamarin

I want to write Android Apps with Visual Studio and Xamarin, because of this I wanted to debug on my Android Samsung S7 Edge but in Visual Studio it didn't show my device.

First of all my Device is shown in Device Monitor is offline

[Picture of Device Monitor show my device but it is offline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0eS9.png)

I tried to solve this problem while searching for a solution with the following steps:

1. Adb kill-server & Adb start-server
2. Plugging phone in and out
3. Disable and Enabled USB-Debugging while plugging in and out
4. Checked if all drivers are installed correctly but it seems as if everything is correctly installed

[Picture of my Android SDK Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMNE3.png)

5. I also tried every connection method (MPT/PTP/MIDI)

Nothing worked until now.

But when I restarted my phone while it is connected, for a short time my phone shows up in Visual Studio but when I click on debugging it shows: "Deployment issues" and then again there is no device shown for debugging.

I Hope anyone has a solution for this, thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your SDK location path ? You could see it in `Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> Android Settings -> SDK Location`

Comment: The path to the SDK shown in Android SDK Manager is: C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted to debug on my Android Samsung S7 Edge but in Visual Studio it didn't show my device.

- Open Registry Editor by selecting **Run** from the Start buttons context menu, typing **regedit** in the dialog box, and choosing **OK**.
- Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Android SDK Tools` in the folder tree on the left
- Modify the Path registry variable to **match the path to your Android SDK**.

[image]

Restart the emulator and you should now be able to see the emulator connected to ADB and associated Android tools.

Here is the [official document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228282.aspx#Anchor_8).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Sadly the path shown in my registry already shows the path to my android sdk. (C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk)

Comment: @Nick77,  can you  deploy your project in an Android emulator?

Comment: @Nick77, Make sure the **Google USBDriver** is installed using the Android SDK Manager.

Comment: Sorry, no I hadn't time to answer. I installed some sort of usb driver manually but it didn't helped.Sadly I can't install the google usb driver throughout android sdk manager. I saw picture of how to to it with Android studio and SDK Manager but I don't have those options in my SDK Manager ( Visual studio )

Comment: But I see down in "Extras" in android SDK Manager that Google USB Driver seems to be installed.